# Why the max-min allocation problem is a linear programming problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

To my understanding, a linear programming problem is to find

$$ \max_x \quad v^T x \quad \text{subject to} \quad A x \le b $$

And the max-min allocation problem is as the following: there is a set $P$ of players, a set $R$ of resources where each resource $r\in R$ has a value $v_r>0$, and each player $p\in P$ covets a set $L_p\subseteq R$.

An allocation is a function $f: P\rightarrow 2^R$ such that $f(p)\subseteq L_p$ and $f(p)\cap f(q)=\emptyset$ if $p\neq q$. The min-value of allocation $f$ is $$\min_{p\in P}\sum_{r\in f(p)}v_r.$$

The objective is to maximize the min-value over all allocations. Why is this a linear program?

Can we rewrite $\max_{f}\min_{p\in P}\sum_{r\in f(p)}v_r$ as $\min$ or $\max$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like below:
define $0 \le z$ as a var then add constraints
$ z \le \sum_{r\in f(p)} v_r \ \ \forall p$
Or alternatively
$ z \le \sum_r \tau_{rp}v_r \ \ \forall p$
where $ \tau_{rp}=1$ if $r$ is associated with player $p$ or whatever $ L_p$ implies, otherwise 0

Then max $z$